# ParentalKey is not rendered within the StructBlock

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm trying to create a custom `StructBlock` which I wanna use inside the `StreamField`. Here in the `StructBlock` I have 4 fields, namely:

- background_style
- title
- image
- category

That's my code:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import StreamField

from wagtail.wagtailcore import blocks
from wagtail.wagtailimages.blocks import ImageChooserBlock
from wagtail.wagtailimages.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.wagtailsnippets.models import register_snippet

from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

from .vars import BackgroundChoices


class BaseBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    background_style = blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=BackgroundChoices, icon='color', required=False)


@register_snippet
class LeadCaptureCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    icon = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('about'),
        ImageChooserPanel('icon'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Lead Capture Categories'


class LeadCaptureForm(BaseBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock(required=False)
    image = ImageChooserBlock(required=False)
    category = blocks.BlockField(ParentalKey('LeadCaptureCategory'))

    class Meta:
        icon = 'plus-inverse'
        label = 'lead capture form'.title()
        admin_text = label
        template = 'home/blocks/lead_capture_form.html'


class HomePage(Page):
    template = 'home/home_page.html'
    menu = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    body = StreamField([
        ('lead_capture_form', LeadCaptureForm()),
    ], blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

3 of these fields in the `admin` are rendered correctly, except `category` (which doesn't render at all). You can see that the `category` is based on the `modelcluster.fields.ParentalKey`. Could that be the problem?

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

```
In [27]: wagtail.__version__
Out[27]: '1.13.1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you can't build a block from a ParentalKey like that. It looks like what you really want is a `SnippetChooserBlock`:

```
from wagtail.wagtailsnippets.blocks import SnippetChooserBlock

class LeadCaptureForm(BaseBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock(required=False)
    image = ImageChooserBlock(required=False)
    category = SnippetChooserBlock(LeadCaptureCategory)
```

Comment: I knew this is gonna be easy like a breeze. Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Yep - http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/streamfield.html#snippetchooserblock